# Spring Roo - binding entity to controller method paramter field

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have roo entity with one reference filed:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class ActivatedConfiguration {

  @NotNull
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Configuration configuration;

  ...
}
```

In Spring controller i have annotated mathod with that entity as a parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String startActivation(ActivatedConfiguration activatedConfiguration){
...
}
```

When i prepared HTML GET request:

```
http://localhost:8080/app?configuration=1&[...]
```

spring automagicaly injected that field.

The question is: From where that magic come from ? How can i mock database fetching in my junit tests ?

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by [Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) which are registered with Spring MVC - if you look into your web folder, you should see a ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj class with all the different Converters for your application - there should be one which takes in a String and converts it to your `Configuration` class, what that essentially does is take in an id as String, converts that to long and then looks up the repository  for `Configuration` entities with that id, and that is how Spring MVC binds the parameters.

Comment: Thans for answer! I found FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.java instead. Where should i search for `Configuration` class converter.

Comment: There should be a corresponding .aj file with the Converter, can you please look in the same folder

Comment: The only aspect files in my project are in package where i have my entity classes.

Comment: Since I don't have access to you code, let me instead show where the Converters are for a sample project that comes with Spring roo - petclinic.roo - if you run the scripts the Converters are in the `com.springsource.petclinic.web` package - `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj` file. Can you please check this out, you should be able to find your converters along the same lines

Comment: As i read on project site: `With the introduction of Spring Framework 3.0 this sample application is no longer part of the distribution. The code is now maintained as part of a separate source repository for samples.` I should write in post that i am using spring 3.0...

Comment: My project doesn't contain any `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean_Roo_ConversionService.aj` file or any of aspect filed despite of those in `domain` classes package. Thanks for response.

Comment: I find out that this aspect file was previously in repo but was accidentally removed from it. How the magic works now then ?

Comment: I discovered that roo remove that file when i removed all default controllers with annotation @RooWebScaffold(path = "configuration", formBackingObject = Configuration.class). By why convertion still take place?